# Use of coalesce with temporary variables in sql and concept of single quotes?

Tags: sql, temporary

I have made a stored procedure,
i am getting an error due to misplaced single quotes perhaps ->`INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR = in (@l=coalesce).` Can it be helped !!!??

CODE:

```
set @q= N'select '+@l=COALESCE(@l+',','')+'+attribute_names FROM'+
@tablename
print @q
EXEC sp_executesql @q
```

Comment: can you provide the printed value of `@query`?

Comment: No , i have shortened the query... There is an error ->  " incorrect syntax near @l = or expectd select or ( ". Can anyone help in the placement of quotes !!!!

Comment: I think you should set the l variable seperately. And then @q='bla'+@l+'bla'. Also you need to delete extra plus in `+'+attribute_names F` as `+' attribute_names F`